# PCA or MCA for binarized data

Tags: pca

I am working with bioinformatics and I have data that looks like the following:

```
    H3K18Ac H3K27me3    H3K36me3    H3K4me1 H3K4me2 H3K4me3 H3K9Ac  H4K12Ac PolII
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
|                                   
|                                   
308792  0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

So I have about 300,000 observations of 9 variables. They are binarized (ie the only value the variable could have is 0/1). I was told by my professor to run PCA on this. The goal is to determine the independence of the variables. After doing some research, it turns out that PCA is only for continuous variables and what I am looking for is MCA/MFA. This is because (and I am guessing here) that my data is categorical rather than continuous. Is this correct?

My question has two parts.  Basically, I am trying to get an intuition on what PCA/MCA/MFA mean and their statistical interpretation.

EDIT: Based on the answer below, I ran PCA on my data. This is what I got back as a summary, can someone care to explain what it all means:

```
Call:
PCA(b) 


Eigenvalues
                       Dim.1   Dim.2   Dim.3   Dim.4   Dim.5   Dim.6   Dim.7   Dim.8   Dim.9
Variance               3.604   1.115   1.045   0.938   0.713   0.539   0.456   0.300   0.290
% of var.             40.050  12.390  11.612  10.426   7.925   5.986   5.061   3.332   3.217
Cumulative % of var.  40.050  52.440  64.052  74.478  82.403  88.390  93.451  96.783 100.000

Individuals (the 10 first)
             Dist    Dim.1    ctr   cos2    Dim.2    ctr   cos2    Dim.3    ctr   cos2  
1        |  0.699 | -0.542  0.000  0.602 | -0.137  0.000  0.038 | -0.101  0.000  0.021 |
2        |  0.699 | -0.542  0.000  0.602 | -0.137  0.000  0.038 | -0.101  0.000  0.021 |
3        |  0.699 | -0.542  0.000  0.602 | -0.137  0.000  0.038 | -0.101  0.000  0.021 |
4        |  0.699 | -0.542  0.000  0.602 | -0.137  0.000  0.038 | -0.101  0.000  0.021 |
5        |  0.699 | -0.542  0.000  0.602 | -0.137  0.000  0.038 | -0.101  0.000  0.021 |
6        |  0.699 | -0.542  0.000  0.602 | -0.137  0.000  0.038 | -0.101  0.000  0.021 |
7        |  0.699 | -0.542  0.000  0.602 | -0.137  0.000  0.038 | -0.101  0.000  0.021 |
8        |  0.699 | -0.542  0.000  0.602 | -0.137  0.000  0.038 | -0.101  0.000  0.021 |
9        |  0.699 | -0.542  0.000  0.602 | -0.137  0.000  0.038 | -0.101  0.000  0.021 |
10       |  0.699 | -0.542  0.000  0.602 | -0.137  0.000  0.038 | -0.101  0.000  0.021 |

Variables
            Dim.1    ctr   cos2    Dim.2    ctr   cos2    Dim.3    ctr   cos2  
H3K18Ac  |  0.500  6.943  0.250 |  0.651 38.002  0.424 |  0.271  7.036  0.074 |
H3K27me3 | -0.084  0.195  0.007 | -0.372 12.421  0.139 |  0.584 32.635  0.341 |
H3K36me3 |  0.115  0.365  0.013 |  0.126  1.421  0.016 | -0.763 55.679  0.582 |
H3K4me1  |  0.555  8.543  0.308 |  0.593 31.535  0.352 |  0.175  2.933  0.031 |
H3K4me2  |  0.835 19.327  0.697 | -0.167  2.512  0.028 |  0.041  0.157  0.002 |
H3K4me3  |  0.796 17.592  0.634 | -0.253  5.760  0.064 | -0.046  0.207  0.002 |
H3K9Ac   |  0.845 19.828  0.715 | -0.190  3.249  0.036 |  0.001  0.000  0.000 |
H4K12Ac  |  0.800 17.736  0.639 | -0.085  0.643  0.007 | -0.035  0.116  0.001 |
PolII    |  0.584  9.472  0.341 | -0.223  4.457  0.050 | -0.114  1.236  0.013 |

> res$eig
       eigenvalue percentage of variance cumulative percentage of variance
comp 1  3.6044591              40.049546                          40.04955
comp 2  1.1151142              12.390158                          52.43970
comp 3  1.0451003              11.612225                          64.05193
comp 4  0.9383536              10.426151                          74.47808
comp 5  0.7132522               7.925025                          82.40311
comp 6  0.5387807               5.986452                          88.38956
comp 7  0.4555308               5.061453                          93.45101
comp 8  0.2998385               3.331539                          96.78255
comp 9  0.2895705               3.217450                         100.00000

> res$var
    $coord
               Dim.1       Dim.2        Dim.3        Dim.4        Dim.5
H3K18Ac   0.50024249  0.65096914  0.271178606  0.082130491  0.179898889
H3K27me3 -0.08393274 -0.37216436  0.584012215  0.716196755 -0.004918553
H3K36me3  0.11467656  0.12589380 -0.762825333  0.613452477 -0.066302036
H3K4me1   0.55491452  0.59300598  0.175082970  0.171327973 -0.090682110
H3K4me2   0.83463853 -0.16735597  0.040521897 -0.068620027 -0.192035432
H3K4me3   0.79629230 -0.25344621 -0.046489758 -0.054375461 -0.220167476
H3K9Ac    0.84540049 -0.19034355  0.001356118 -0.070513987 -0.087435840
H4K12Ac   0.79955158 -0.08468939 -0.034841216  0.003741303 -0.079640892
PolII     0.58429734 -0.22292558 -0.113651084  0.018482152  0.754258704

$cor
               Dim.1       Dim.2        Dim.3        Dim.4        Dim.5
H3K18Ac   0.50024249  0.65096914  0.271178606  0.082130491  0.179898889
H3K27me3 -0.08393274 -0.37216436  0.584012215  0.716196755 -0.004918553
H3K36me3  0.11467656  0.12589380 -0.762825333  0.613452477 -0.066302036
H3K4me1   0.55491452  0.59300598  0.175082970  0.171327973 -0.090682110
H3K4me2   0.83463853 -0.16735597  0.040521897 -0.068620027 -0.192035432
H3K4me3   0.79629230 -0.25344621 -0.046489758 -0.054375461 -0.220167476
H3K9Ac    0.84540049 -0.19034355  0.001356118 -0.070513987 -0.087435840
H4K12Ac   0.79955158 -0.08468939 -0.034841216  0.003741303 -0.079640892
PolII     0.58429734 -0.22292558 -0.113651084  0.018482152  0.754258704

$cos2
               Dim.1       Dim.2        Dim.3        Dim.4        Dim.5
H3K18Ac  0.250242546 0.423760821 7.353784e-02 6.745418e-03 3.236361e-02
H3K27me3 0.007044705 0.138506309 3.410703e-01 5.129378e-01 2.419216e-05
H3K36me3 0.013150713 0.015849249 5.819025e-01 3.763239e-01 4.395960e-03
H3K4me1  0.307930129 0.351656088 3.065405e-02 2.935327e-02 8.223245e-03
H3K4me2  0.696621476 0.028008020 1.642024e-03 4.708708e-03 3.687761e-02
H3K4me3  0.634081430 0.064234980 2.161298e-03 2.956691e-03 4.847372e-02
H3K9Ac   0.714701983 0.036230668 1.839057e-06 4.972222e-03 7.645026e-03
H4K12Ac  0.639282736 0.007172292 1.213910e-03 1.399735e-05 6.342672e-03
PolII    0.341403380 0.049695815 1.291657e-02 3.415899e-04 5.689062e-01

$contrib
              Dim.1     Dim.2        Dim.3        Dim.4       Dim.5
H3K18Ac   6.9425825 38.001561 7.036438e+00  0.718856660  4.53747063
H3K27me3  0.1954442 12.420818 3.263517e+01 54.663590856  0.00339181
H3K36me3  0.3648457  1.421312 5.567911e+01 40.104703429  0.61632615
H3K4me1   8.5430330 31.535431 2.933120e+00  3.128167613  1.15292246
H3K4me2  19.3266578  2.511673 1.571164e-01  0.501805286  5.17034591
H3K4me3  17.5915835  5.760395 2.068029e-01  0.315093446  6.79615372
H3K9Ac   19.8282728  3.249054 1.759695e-04  0.529887903  1.07185451
H4K12Ac  17.7358854  0.643189 1.161525e-01  0.001491692  0.88926070
PolII     9.4716952  4.456567 1.235917e+00  0.036403115 79.76227412
```

Comment: Check out the related material at http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pca+binary.  The highest voted one at http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5774 might be particularly helpful.  Since you're new to PCA, make sure to look over the answers at http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2691 too.

Comment: masfenix, Please de-cipher all the acronyms in your question. PCA, MCA, MFA... Otherwise, how can a reader know what they mean?!

Comment: PCA - Principle Component Analysis, MCA - Multiple Component Analysis, MFA - Multiple Factor Analysis

Answer (score 2):

Just because your data is binary doesn't mean you can't use PCA, it just makes the result a little harder to interpret.

What PCA does essentially is find orthogonal directions in an $N$ dimensional space (in your case $N=9$) which explain the most variance in your data.

It's by no means perfect, but it will very quickly give you some intuition of the dimensionality of your data.

Comment: Okay thanks. The PCA command worked perfectly. But I am fairly certain that the plot it gives me has 300,000 points or so which takes forever to render. My question is what is exactly shown on the graph?

Comment: Don't look at the PCA transform, look at the components themselves and at the eigenvalues. The components should be 9 orthogonal weight vectors of 9 dimension each, and you should have 9 positive eigenvalues. 

Then you can try plotting a scatterplot of the first two dimensions of the transform, corresponding to the two most important axes.

Comment: From what I see the plot it gives me is a scatterplot of the first two dimensions. So what exactly is being "scattered" here, ie what is the interpretation of the values? I've added the summary in my answer. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Well, are you interested in predicting something? In that case you could color the points according to that value and see if a pattern emerges

Comment: Also can you post the eigenvalues?

Comment: I've posted the eigenvalues plus additional information. Note that the default dimension is 5 (but I am not sure what this really means). I am currently doing more reading on PCA. I am interested in seeing independence of the variables (if that makes sense).

Comment: `it just makes the result a little harder to interpret` Elaborating this statement might be crucial (and make the answer really good then).

Comment: Actually you have enough data that you can get away with just counting the number of occurrence of every 9-bit vector

Comment: Hi @ArthurB. What do you mean by counting the number of occurrence of every 9bit vector? Also, back to my original question.. since this is binary data are the results okay to interpret?

Comment: Sorry for the second comment, I also have a plot  but need help understanding it. http://i.imgur.com/ytMWuPi.png