# Is it effective to use one hot encoding of categorical data as input to PCA for anomaly detection?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, categorical-encoding, anomaly-detection, correspondence-analysis

I have a mixture of numeric and categorical inputs, the categorical inputs are relatively low cardinality (perhaps 10-15).

I want to use PCA for anomaly detection, but am not sure how best to encode the categorical attributes.

Will one hot encoding work, and if not, what should I try?

Answer (score 1):

I would not try pca, but rather correspondence analysis (or some its generalization to mixed categorical/continuous data.)  See [Can principal component analysis be applied to datasets containing a mix of continuous and categorical variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont/5777#5777)  for ideas and linkt to generalizations such as homogeneity analysis.

Comment: I may support this. Dummy coding of nominal variables in PCA leads essentially to a (Multiple) Correspondence analysis (MCA). Categorical PCA (CATPCA) is a technique which incorporates them both. It allows a mixture of numeric, ordinal, nominal variables and does dimensionality reduction quantifying them optimally.