# FA for mixed data types, including dichotomous

Tags: pca, data-visualization, factor-analysis, mixed-type-data

I wish to conduct factor analysis on data that I have. The data is collected from a questionnaire and contains different types of data, for example, there are answers to the following questions:

```
What is your age? (Number)
What is your gender? (4 - Female, 5 - Male)
Which country are you from? (Number - different number assigned to different country)
Do you have a smartphone? (0 or 1)
Do you have a tablet? (0 or 1)
Do you have an activity tracker? (0 or 1)
What is your level of education? (0,1,2 or 3)
How many days will you input data? (Any number between 0 and 100)
```

and then one I have combined one more question which is obtained from an app, not a questionnaire and it answers the question:

```
How many days was data input (for this particular person)? 
(Any number from greater than 0)
```

I am trying to "categorise" types of people based on these questions. I want to understand any patterns or correlations occurring between all these different dimensions.

At first, I started out conducting PCA on this data but quickly realised, after reading lots of posts on here about PCA, that this is probably wrong given my data is quite different and it would be hard to find meaningful correlations between these different types of data. So I moved on to factor analysis which is better at handling this type of data (or that's my understanding). What I don't understand is that can I only do the analysis on the data that is similar? For example, can I only compare the data that has answers O's and 1's with each other or can I still conduct FA on this?

I am new to both PCA and FA and would really appreciate any guidance! Many of the posts on this forum have been massively useful in furthering my understanding but this is sort of the last point that is unclear to me.

Comment: Factor analysis give you latent factors. Is that what u want?

Comment: I have added in some more information to say what I am trying to achieve

Comment: `So I moved on to factor analysis which is better at handling this type of data (or that's my understanding)` Strange understanding. FA is even more demanding in respect to data type than PCA. Did you browse local Qs on FA and data type (e.g. [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/215404/3277) and other)?

Comment: FA is a modeling of latent traits [generating](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/123089/3277) the manifest variables or generating their correlatedness. In proper sense of the term, "factor analysis" is only for scale (interval) data. For other types, other **latent variable** procedures exist.

Comment: I was going by this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont which you linked in your post. I have been trying to use polychoric correlation to create the "correct" type of correlation matrix.. What other techiques would you recommend?

Comment: @maheen clarify the purpose of your study ? There are several methods for a statistical analysis.

Comment: @subhash I am trying to "categorise" types of people based on these questions. I want to understand any patterns or correlations occurring between all these different dimensions.

Comment: Honestly, I would not recommend doing a latent variable analysis on variables on _mixed_ types. Especially for someone who is new to the field of latent variables. Working with mixed types is always questionable theoretically and is slippery practically.

Comment: If you  want to `"categorise" types of people` that would be closer to a cluster analysis which isn't necessarily a latent trait technique.

Comment: Well I started off hoping to better visualise (and understand) my data using PCA then moving on to cluster analysis... but I have ended up here as I don't think PCA is appropriate. In addition, when I did PCA I would need to retain most of the components to retain at least 80% variance. But I guess FA isn't appropriate either...

Comment: Why strangely did you change the title to "dichotomous data"? The data you show is not only dichotomous, - there's a bunch of types of data there.

Comment: Sorry, I meant dichotomous and numerical data... I think I should change it to mixed types

Comment: You should first work out your set of various hypotheses and that will indicate the statistical analysis you need to employ. also tag  the question as self-study.

Comment: @subhashc.davar I am trying to look at hidden patterns in my data. I don't have any formed hypotheses.

Comment: There are generalizations of principal component analysis for mixed data types, which goes under various names. Search this site for homegeneity analysis.