# PCA with continuous and categorical features

Tags: pca

I have a dataset with both continuous and categorical features. 
I want to reduce the dimensionality, but cannot apply PCA directly on the dataset because of the categorical features.

One solution I thought of was to run PCA exclusively on the continuous features, reduce the dimensions there, and then add the categorical features as they are to the reduced table with the continuous features.

I have not seen this method anywhere, but it makes sense to me, so I was wondering if it's OK.

Comment: that really depends on what type of data/problem you have

Comment: @redress can you please elaborate. Right now, I just want to reduce features. What I'm suggesting is that all categorical features stay, but at least I can reduce the number of continuous features, even if they lose their interpretability.

Comment: how many different classes exist in each category?  what is the actual complexity of the categorical data?

Answer (score -1):

You can binaries your categorical features. Try to google and learn about **One-of-k coding**. That way you end up with only numerical data.

And if you do that I will suggest that you standardize your numerical features.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont

My way is being criticized here. Worth a read

Comment: Even if I binarize categorical features, I will end up with discrete binary features (which, while numerical, are not continuous and therefore not naturally used in PCA)

Comment: Could you state a reference of PCA requiring continuous data?