# How I can work with data set contains both numerical and non-numerical features?

Tags: r

I have a dataset contains both numerical and non-numerical columns. 
I want to use PCA, is there any way to handle both?

Comment: PCA is defined for real-valued data, but there are various methods for generalizing it to other data types. Many have been covered on this site. What type of data do you have?

Comment: Perhaps see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont/5777#5777 which may help you.