# Convert two categoricals variables to numeric one - PCA FactoMineR

Tags: r, pca

I am currently working on the CPA with R and I have a problem.
My data are all numerical, except for two columns that represent a "category" (the sampling site and the land use type)
At first I foolishly replaced these data with numerical identifiers (A:1, B:2, C:3 ...), but this method implies that A < B < C. I don't know if this is really a problem for PCAs, but A is definitely not < B nor B < C.

Is there a way to convert a text data into a numerical data without biasing the results to make a PCA ?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont

Comment: One hint: CATPCA