# Should I Include 'Year' Column in PCA

Tags: r, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I want to do dimensionality reduction on a dataset. One of the columns present is the Year and the values are 2000, up to 2015. When doing PCA, do you treat this column as a factor or as numeric?

Comment: To include it in a PCA you'd have to treat it as numeric.  There are alternatives to PCA, though, that can handle categorical variables:  you could look up "categorical PCA" or "CATPCA".

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be treated as a categorical variable. Maybe [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont) can help.